# Alfresco Community corruption after install an amp file

Tags: postgresql, tomcat, alfresco, alfresco-share

Recently, I installed the latest Alfresco Community version available (Alfresco 201602 Community) for Windows x64. After the install, I will to install some module packages, specifically Alfresco PDF Toolkit. I follow the steps of the documentation (http://docs.alfresco.com/4.1/tasks/amp-install.html)

After that, I start up Alfresco and I go to /share but all my credentials are gone (the admin user and the other users created). The logging page shows a message similar to: “authentication failed or alfresco not available”. After reinstall Alfresco, I tried the same with another amp file (https://addons.alfresco.com/addons/share-site-creators), but I get the same result.

Someone has had the same problem or knows what happens?

Here the log file "alfrescotomcat-stdout.2016-04-26.log" at /tomcat/logs.

The alf_data directory hasn't been removed, neither the database and the alfresco-global-properties

```
09:08:45,322 WARN  [org.alfresco.wcm.client.util.impl.GuestSessionFactoryImpl] WQS unable to connect to repository: No Encontrado
    09:08:47,332 WARN  [org.alfresco.wcm.client.util.impl.GuestSessionFactoryImpl] WQS unable to connect to repository: No Encontrado
    09:08:49,358 WARN  [org.alfresco.wcm.client.util.impl.GuestSessionFactoryImpl] WQS unable to connect to repository: No Encontrado
    09:08:51,367 WARN  [org.alfresco.wcm.client.util.impl.GuestSessionFactoryImpl] WQS unable to connect to repository: No Encontrado
    09:08:53,377 WARN  [org.alfresco.wcm.client.util.impl.GuestSessionFactoryImpl] WQS unable to connect to repository: No Encontrado'
```

Thanks.

Comment: Please post logs file. It locate in alfresco-directory/tomcat/logs.
Likely, you need recreate database and clear indexes

Comment: What you describe indicates that the Alfresco repository is not started correctly. Please look into the log file for errors.

Comment: I updated the question with the log file information

Answer (score 2):

Installing an AMP will not remove data. Installing an AMP merges what is in the AMP with the Alfresco WAR and Share WAR. If you are using apply_amps to do this, the script will merge the AMPs with the WARs, then it removes the expanded WAR files from Tomcat's webapps directory. If you've made any customizations or configuration changes within TOMCAT_HOME/alfresco or TOMCAT_HOME/share that are not included in an AMP those changes will be lost.

If data is missing from your repository, I suspect that either the alf_data directory has been removed (again, apply_amps will not do this), your database has been dropped, or the alfresco-global.properties file which points to both of these things has been changed to point to different locations (or different database host/credentials).